# Custom configuration section in app.config - XML attributes Vs elements

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, app-config

I already have a custom configuration section working, based on config like:

```
  <DataSourcesConfig>
    <DataSources>
      <DataSource name="test1" connectionType="Ethernet_TCP_Client" protocolType="Serial" ipAddress="127.0.0.1" port="12345"/>
      <DataSource name="test2" connectionType="Ethernet_TCP_Client" protocolType="Serial" ipAddress="127.0.0.1" port="12346"/>
    </DataSources>
  </DataSourcesConfig>
```

But I was wondering about supporting the following - or in an ideal world supporting both:

```
  <DataSourcesConfig>
    <DataSources>
      <DataSource>
        <name>test1</name>
        <connectionType>Ethernet_TCP_Client</connectionType>
        <protocolType>Serial</protocolType>
        <ipAddress>127.0.0.1</ipAddress>
        <port>12345</port>
      </DataSource>
      <DataSource>
        <name>test2</name>
        <connectionType>Ethernet_TCP_Client</connectionType>
        <protocolType>Serial</protocolType>
        <ipAddress>127.0.0.1</ipAddress>
        <port>12346</port>
      </DataSource>
    </DataSources>
  </DataSourcesConfig>
```

So I have code (working) as follows. Is supporting the second Xml example practical without doing custom Xml parsing?
I can see for a start `DataSources.GetElementKey` is a problem as it references `name` which is missing as an attribute but this is largely borrowed from example code so I don't claim to understand these classes very well.

```
public class DataSource : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Name => this["name"] as string;

    [ConfigurationProperty("connectionType", IsRequired = true)]
    public string ConnectionType => this["connectionType"] as string;

    [ConfigurationProperty("protocolType", IsRequired = true)]
    public string ProtocolType => this["protocolType"] as string;

    [ConfigurationProperty("ipAddress", IsRequired = true)]
    public string IPAddress => this["ipAddress"] as string;

    [ConfigurationProperty("port", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Port => this["port"] as string;
}
public class DataSources
    : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    public DataSource this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return base.BaseGet(index) as DataSource;
        }
        set
        {
            if (base.BaseGet(index) != null)
            {
                base.BaseRemoveAt(index);
            }
            BaseAdd(index, value);
        }
    }

    public new DataSource this[string responseString]
    {
        get
        {
            return (DataSource)BaseGet(responseString);
        }
        set
        {
            if (BaseGet(responseString) != null)
            {
                BaseRemoveAt(BaseIndexOf(BaseGet(responseString)));
            }
            BaseAdd(value);
        }
    }

    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new DataSource();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((DataSource)element).Name;
    }
}

public class DataSourcesConfig : ConfigurationSection
{
    public static DataSourcesConfig GetConfig()
    {
        var o = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("DataSourcesConfig");
        return o as DataSourcesConfig;
    }

    [System.Configuration.ConfigurationProperty("DataSources")]
    [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(DataSources), AddItemName = "DataSource")]
    public DataSources DataSources
    {
        get
        {
            object o = this["DataSources"];
            return o as DataSources;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Honestly, can't get what you're trying to achieve. What your question about? Can you be more clarify with that?

Comment: I've given you the exact XML I would like to be able to use as a config file, properties as discrete elements `<setting>something</setting>` Vs `setting="something"`... I'm asking if this fits the .Net libraries and if so how I'd tweak custom config code to support it.

Comment: Is your application .NET Framework or .NET Core? Is that a desktop or web application?

Comment: Besides dotnet, they do not mean the same thing semantically in XML. https://www.devever.net/~hl/xml

Comment: @ZaferBalkan yes I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know, you can't place **values** in xml sections in app.config file while using `ConfigurationManager`

But you have a quite similar option to work with config structures like that:

```xml
<DataSourcesConfig>
    <DataSources>
        <DataSource>
            <name value="test1"/>
            <connectionType value="Ethernet_TCP_Client"/>
            <protocolType value="Serial"/>
            <ipAddress value="127.0.0.1"/>
            <port value="12345"/>
        </DataSource>
        <DataSource>
            <name value="test2"/>
            <connectionType value="Ethernet_TCP_Client"/>
            <protocolType value="Serial"/>
            <ipAddress value="127.0.0.1"/>
            <port value="12346"/>
        </DataSource>
    </DataSources>
</DataSourcesConfig>
```

First of all, you need to define an `ValueElement`:

```cs
public class ValueElement<T> : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("value", IsRequired = true)]
    public T Value => (T) this["value"];
}
```

Next, change your `DataSource` element like that:

```cs
public class DataSource : ConfigurationSection // It is section now
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsRequired = true)]
    public ValueElement<string> Name => this["name"] as ValueElement<string>;

    [ConfigurationProperty("connectionType", IsRequired = true)]
    public ValueElement<string> ConnectionType => this["connectionType"] as ValueElement<string>;

    [ConfigurationProperty("protocolType", IsRequired = true)]
    public ValueElement<string> ProtocolType => this["protocolType"] as ValueElement<string>;

    [ConfigurationProperty("ipAddress", IsRequired = true)]
    public ValueElement<string> IPAddress => this["ipAddress"] as ValueElement<string>;

    [ConfigurationProperty("port", IsRequired = true)]
    public ValueElement<int> Port => this["port"] as ValueElement<int>;
}
```

Now you can use your config in code like that:

```cs
var configuration = DataSourcesConfig.GetConfig();
var test1name = configuration.DataSources[0].Name.Value; // test1 as string
var test2name = configuration.DataSources[1].Name.Value; // test2 as string
var portForTest1 = configuration.DataSources[0].Port.Value // 12345 as int
```

Comment: I notice you cast `this["value"]` to `string`, `int`, etc. I hadn't realised .Net would automatically let you do that, I figured everything was presented as string and would have to be parsed?

Comment: Also what if you changed `public ValueElement<string> Name => this["name"] as ValueElement<string>` to `public string Name => (this["name"] as ValueElement<string>).Value`? Is there any reason this wouldn't work?

Comment: @Mr.Boy Well, it is just an additional useful code for typesafe. If some configuration value does not match declared type - you will receive an `InvalidCastException`. There are also no reasons your code snippet wouldn't work.

Comment: I hope I got the bounty to you in time, missed it was expiring!